# Counting characters in a p:textArea does not work when webpage is loaded while text box is inactive

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces

I've been stuck on a problem for a little while now with little success. I am in web development and I need to count the amount of characters used in a text box.

The textbox is linked to a checkbox marked "other". The textbox is only active when the checkbox is selected. I am using jQuery to count the characters used however it does not work in certain situations. If I load the webpage while the "other" checkbox is not clicked, and therefore the textArea is not active, the characters counter does not work. However, if I refresh the webpage with the "other" checkbox clicked, and therefore the textArea is active, the counter works.

Below are snapshots of the code used for the textbox and to count characters.

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
            function(){
                var countCharactersRecTools = function() {
                    var maxChars = 50;
                    var commentText = $('#documentForm\\:recommendedToolsOther').val();
                    var currentCharCount = 0;

                    if (commentText != null) {
                        currentCharCount = commentText.length;
                        if (currentCharCount > maxChars) {
                            var trimmedText = commentText.substring(0, maxChars);
                            $('#documentForm\\:recommendedToolsOther').val(trimmedText);
                            currentCharCount=maxChars;
                        }
                    }
                    $('#documentForm\\:recToolsCommentsCounter').text(currentCharCount + "/" + maxChars);
                };
                $('#documentForm\\:recommendedToolsOther').keyup(countCharactersRecTools);
            }
        );
 </script>
```

xhtml:

```
<p:inputTextarea id="recommendedToolsOther" rows="1"            style="vertical-align: top; width: 98% !important;"    styleClass="preformatted" autoResize="false"
                        value="#{rfeBean.rfe.otherRecommendedTools}"
                        disabled="#{!rfeBean.recommendedToolsChecked[ReferralTemplateConstants.RECOMMENDED_TOOLS_HAND_OTHER] or !    raudUserSessionBean.raudUser.referMode or  rfeBean.workItemMissing}">
                        <p:ajax event="change"  update="recommendedToolsOther"/>
                    </p:inputTextarea>
                    <br/>
                    <h:outputText id="recToolsCommentsCounter" value="#{rfeBean.getRecToolsOtherCount()}/50" />
```

[Primefaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBE1p.png)
[jQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9eY4.png)

There is some Java in the background however I'm fairly sure the problem is with the jQuery and/or primefaces.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Code should be posted here, directly.

Comment: Yes, please improve your question with a [mcve]

Comment: I think you should at least invoke the function once on document ready, then subscribe keyup events.

Comment: `$('#documentForm\\:recommendedToolsOther')` does not match with the xhtml... there is no form in it and `#{rfeBean.rfe.otherRecommendedTools}` is nowhere either... [mcve] please... And PrimeFaces is just a 'rendering' engine in this regard. Client-side it is all html/javascript/css

Comment: @Kukeltje $('#documentForm\\:recommendedToolsOther') references the inputTextArea (notice its id is the same). Similarly with the $('#documentForm\\:recToolsCommentsCounter'), it references the outputText.

Comment: I **know** what it (should) reference, but in this way someone cannot try to reproduce what is wrong since he/she would need to add extra code (a `<h:form id="documentForm">...` that is not in your example and that could mean there is more code in it that is not shown but relevant... Actually, there is, the checkboxes, the bean and more... Hence the request to make a [mcve]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665649/primefaces-count-characters-used-instead-of-characters-remaining Hi, I posted another question, hopefully its a little clearer. I am going for a different approach in that one.

Comment: Then remove this question... The answer below is not good (bad even) and if you created a new question and are not proceeding down the road of this one it has become 'useless' to answer